# Reanimated: Couldn't determine the version of the native part of Reanimated

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I am Trying to use expo router with SDK 50 and i wanted to put drawer in my app and by following documentation i downloaded gesture handler and react native reanimated with it but i got this error even tho same things been working in the older version before but now i am getting this error
I have already tried npm install and tried clearing cache and npx expo start --clear none have worked also i tried  run:andriod

any help ? also the animations are not working

```
const DrawerSceneWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const progress = useDrawerProgress();
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      { scale: interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [1, 0.8], "clamp") },
      {
        rotateY: `${interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, -10], "clamp")}deg`,
      },
      { translateX: interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, 0, -60], "clamp") },
    ],
    borderRadius: interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, 28], "clamp"),
    overflow: "hidden",
  }));
  return (
    <Animated.View className="flex-1" style={animatedStyle}>
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

i been using this in the older version and been working as a charm wrapping my pages

Comment: I am faced with the same issue. Let's hope someone with better knowledge can help.

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed with expo 50.0.4

To upgrade expo version run:

```
yarn add expo@latest
```

And to to upgrade reanimated (and all dependencies) to match this SDK version just run

```
npx expo install --fix
```